# How to check users for a named pipe without admin rights?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, named-pipes, docker-for-windows

I'm using a machine with no admin privileges. When trying to set-up docker, the admin used the code below (from [this github repo](https://github.com/tfenster/dockeraccesshelper)) to give my user `FullControl` access to the named pipe used by docker:

```
$account="<DOMAIN>\<USERNAME>"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"                                                                                 
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe                                               
$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()                                                                                 
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl                                       
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow                                                  
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)                                                                                        
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
```

After that, I checked that docker was working properly. But once I've switched from Windows Containers to Linux containers, it stopped working.

In [this page](https://www.axians-infoma.com/techblog/allow-access-to-the-docker-engine-without-admin-rights-on-windows/), the following code is provided to check the permissions for that pipe:

`[System.IO.Directory]::GetAccessControl("\\.\pipe\docker_engine") | Format-Table`

Nice and all, but this code requires admin right, while I'd like to check it myself, hence the question.

Comment: That *doesn't* require admin rights -- if your account actually has full control, it will also be able to check the ACL rules. Hence, if you can't check them, you *don't* have full control (anymore), so it doubles as a check. It is actually possible to grant accounts permission to see an object's permissions even without actual access to the object itself (that's "list contents/read property" permissions, if I'm not mistaken) but generally there's little use for that.

Comment: Incidentally, on my system things are set up so the local group `docker-users` is granted write/read/synchronize rights on the pipe, and it suffices to be added to that group to have permission (all of which was done by the Docker Desktop installer). This sounds like a more stable solution than granting individual accounts full control.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm the only user on this machine (which is a physical one, not a server). Would you happen to know if the changed permissions should have normally been retained between machine reboots/docker reinitializations and so on? I'm not sure why the permission was removed.

Comment: No, I have no idea how the Docker app manages that. I imagine the permissions could have been erased/reset to default and the pipe recreated entirely when you switched container methods, as this requires a complete "reboot" of the underlying system. I've never had any trouble with the permissions disappearing on me after reboots, but then again I've let the app manage the permissions after initial installation. (My account is not an admin, I have a separate admin account.)

Comment: Please consider adding the contents of your comments as an answer, I'll upvote it, and as soon as I solve this issue I'll accept one worthy answer (possibly yours)